# CDI extension, how to know the Application name that a bean belongs to

Tags: java, cdi

I am new to CDI and I am writing a new CDI portable extension. My CDI extension will listen to events that are fired by the CDI container. I was wondering if there is a way to tell the name of the application that a class belongs to and what are the events that would provide that information.

by application I mean a ear application archive that is deployed on an application server. My goal is to create an extension that looks into applications deployed and for  each add an annotation on some of it's classes. Each application classes would have a unique annotation. Example if we have app1 and app2 deployed on an app server. I want to create an extension that would annotate all/some classes contained in app1 with with @x1   and all classes of app2 with @x2 and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Application'? What is the goal of your extension?

Comment: What purpose would it serve to give different annotations per EAR? Perhaps there are other ways to achieve your goal. Also, EARs have different classloaders. So, even if you annotate your beans with the "same" class from a JAR in the EAR (i.e. not in the application server's classpath - that would be loaded by a common classloader), this class is different per application at runtime because it is loaded by a different classloader.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no concept of `application` in CDI. There are only `bean archives`. You might be able to determine that - e.g. WAR1 will be a different bean archive than WAR2 which in turn will be different than EAR/lib.

**BUT**, and I cannot stress this enough, the bean archive concept is interpreted slightly differently in Weld and OWB (as CDI implementations) so sticking to this would make in unportable (which probably won't matter since all servers except TomEE use Weld anyway). Truth be told, to even get hold of a bean archive, you might have to rely on Weld API (not just CDI).

But I think it would be wiser to find another way around this - why are you trying to achieve this? What gain is there in annotating beans differently in different archives? Because @Nikos has a good point with class loading. There is a whole new level of mess with EARs and you won't "see" some bean from other archives anyway (as per Java EE umbrella spec).

Comment: well I want to annotate them with different annotations so I can inject them in different points based on that annotation...is there another way to achieve that goal?

Comment: I am not even sure what you do willl work even if you could determine the "application" because of the visibility rules. For instance an EJB jar won't ne able to inject any bean coming from WAR (assuming this is all in EAR). And if you simply deploy multiple WARs (not in EAR) then they won't see wach other at all. Are you taking this into consideration? Also, if you can change the application code, why don't you just alter the bean themselves?